# NSUnknownKeyException UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I recently implemented a new view for my app which has a `UICollectionView` acting as a grid for images to be loaded into:

```
class MemoriesView: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var images_collection: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("memory_image_1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewController
        return cell
    }

}
```

Now the code in this class is most likely totally upsidedown since I had to follow a tutorial for this one. So no personal initiative taken here. Hence perhaps producing this error when I try to segue into this view:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Certi.MemoriesView 0x7fb613f3c8d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageCollectionView.'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ee6ae65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f2c7deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ee6aaa9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010cfb29bb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010d98c320 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010dbbaf41 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010edab4a0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010dbb9924 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d992eea -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d993816 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d993b74 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d999f4f -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 120
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d9c9e44 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1203
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d9da23f -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d9db3af -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010db81ff7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010d8b44a3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000011101459a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111008e70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111008cee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000110ffd475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000011102ac0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010d7f7f7c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7329
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed96a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed8c95c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed8be13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed8b828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001115d7ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010d7fd610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    29  Certi                               0x000000010b92c1fd main + 109
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010fde392d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: This line `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("memory_image_1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewController` doesn't look right... you're dequeueing a cell and forcing a cast to `CollectionViewController`.....

Comment: @EvilGeniusJamie I haven't managed to find any proper tutorial nor documentation on actual implementation of this, so this was just guesswork made of a tutorial I saw. Do you suggest just removing that? Or changing it somehow? The function itself I mean.

Comment: `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("memory_image_1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell`

Update this line as given in comment

Comment: exactly as @PrafulD says, unless you're using a custom class for your cell and need to it at this point. This function is also where you would fill in the data for this particular cell

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started and other tutorials on that site are quite good for beginners, I used them often when I was getting started with iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you did rename our `IBOutlet` `imageCollectionView` to `images_collection`, but did not update this in Storyboard.

To fix this:

- right click your `imageCollectionView` in Storyboard
- remove the link to `Memories View` by clicking the little "x" button

[image]

- Create a new link by dragging from your `IBOutlet` in code to `imageCollectionView` in storyboard

[image]

Comment: This got rid of the error, thanks! I'm taking the other answer into account as well, but since this answer actually solved the issue in question I mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

This function is the problem:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("memory_image_1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewController

return cell
```

You're attempting to convert a `UICollectionViewCell` to a `CollectionViewController`. A simple change to the end of that line:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("memory_image_1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
// see below
return cell
```

will prevent this error, however you'll still get blank cells. The point where I added the comment `\\ see below` is where you need to update the values of `cell` to choose what is displayed on this row. The row can be determined from `indexPath.row` and `indexPath.section` if you're using multiple sections.

Also, if you're using a custom class for your cell which handles views other than the default ones, this is the point you need to cast `cell` to that custom class, instead of `UICollectionViewController`, although I assume since you're still looking at tutorials this is not something you're going to be attempting just yet.

As stated in my comment on the question, the tutorial - https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started - and other tutorials on this site are very good for beginners.

Comment: Thanks for a very elaborate explanation!